# How can I add a scroll bar below a DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have HTML like this:

```
<div style="width: 90rem; overflow-x: auto;">
   <div style="width 130rem;">
                    <div class="w10r">EId</div>
                    <div class="w20r">Name</div>
                    <div class="w10r">Type</div>
                    <div class="w10r">Status</div>
                    <div class="w40r">Objectives</div>
                    <div class="w10r">Tests</div>
                    <div class="w30r">Modified</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I was expecting to see a scroll bar under the inside DIV but instead it appears at the bottom of the page and the whole page area moves to the left / right. Can someone explain how I can make it go just below the inner DIV ?

Comment: try adding `display:inline` inside every `div` with `class=w*r`.

Comment: better delete the question as it may attract negative votes

Comment: @user3127499 no longer possible with the answer in place (deletion, not downvotes)

Comment: what's the problem with people? Really, it's a legit question, I don't get this kind of constant animosity and trying to always find the "errors" and "mistakes". It's small, but how many times did you guys stare at a missing period or something? I'm happy to help Marilou and I never downvoted anyone, only annoying comments with attacks, never someone trying to learn or (much less!!!!!) to help

Comment: @JanDvorak yep forgot that earlier it could be done right ??

Comment: @Fabio you are right but its the way it goes in SO most ppl does not bother to look the question twice and vote it down lat day i posted genuine question but was voted down 4 times

Comment: @Fabio typo questions don't belong here, period. There's even an official close reason specifically for them. They are not useful for future comers. As for annoying comments, which one do you mean? Did you flag it as not constructive?

Comment: Jan, I don't intend to have a fight or anything, just making a comment on how things are around SO. Personally, I think it's more useful to have an answer than to have a pillow fight, but well, to each his/her own. And yes, I flagged them but I don't even care anymore, it's just too tiresome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here: (*missing colon*)

```
<div style="width 130rem;">
```

since you're not defining a width for the inner element, there's nothing to scroll. Try changing it to

```
<div style="width: 130rem;">
```

and it should work. If not, then please post html or jsfiddle, but it should work just with this simple correction

Comment: the missing colon was just when entering it into SO. I will continue to look at this and see if I can find the problem.

Comment: I tested your code and it works once you fix the missing colon typo

Comment: Possible there is something more to my problem and it think it's related to the area that my DIV is placed on. What is happening is that the whole page is getting a scroll bar below it and all of the page moves to the left or right with this scroll bar. I want the page fixed and a small scroll bar below the div only.

Comment: yes, sounds like 99% chances of a problem outside this div, but without seeing the code can't tell

Comment: @Marilou make the parent container to have `width: 100%` instead of `width: 90rem;`.