# How can I put an image to an input button?

Tags: css, image, button

I need to put an image to an input button but it doesn't work with my code.
This is the code, and it says "couldn't load the image", please help me:

```
.button-search {
        background-image: url('images/lupa.png');
        no-repeat scroll center #F1F1F1;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        height: 27px;
        overflow:hidden;
        text-indent: -9999em;
        width: 36px;
        border: none;
        margin-right: 48px;
}
```

Comment: Presumably the URL is wrong, and you have a syntax error in the next line.

Comment: You have a semi-colon after the background-image selector, but before its parameters. `no-repeat scroll center $F1F1F1` are parameters of the `background-image` selector (and should be seen as if on the same line, not that the line break matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

First, you have a semi-colon after the background-image selector, but before its parameters. `no-repeat scroll center $F1F1F1` are parameters of the `background` selector (and should be seen as if on the same line, not that the line break matters). Which brings up the next point: wrong selector.

Second, the correct selector (for what you are doing) is `background` not `background-image`. The `background` selector is a "short-hand" selector, and allows you to set (1) background-image, (2) background-position, (3) background-color, (4) background-repeat, etc. But the `background-image` selector ONLY allows you to set the background image.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3d1ze4jf/)

Here is the corrected code:

```
.button-search {
        background: url('http://placekitten.com/g/50/50')no-repeat scroll center #F1F1F1;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        height: 27px;
        overflow:hidden;
        text-indent: -9999em;
        width: 36px;
        border: none;
        margin-right: 48px;
}
```

Also note that the `text-indent` selector (set to -9999em) will move the button text to the left, and (at -9999em) all the way off the screen -- and possibly into a neighbor's house, their kitchen perhaps. Probably you already know this...?

Answer (score 0):

If you get that error, then you got the image URL wrong.

Comment: are you going to copy all answers and comments? Also, this is not an answer, typos aren't considered answers and should be made as comments, just as David did before you

Comment: @Fabio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321051/how-can-i-add-a-scroll-bar-below-a-div/25321086#25321086

Comment: yes, I did it and mods let me know that, which I wasn't aware of. Besides, I'm not copying answers and comments after they're made, which is hugely disrespectful